# Problems accessing object member in javascript

Tags: javascript, couchdb, evently

In a `_changes/data.js` file I have the following implementation:

```
function(data) {
    var p;
    var tmp = $$("#profile");
    $.log(tmp);
    $.log(tmp.profile);
    if (undefined != tmp.profile) {
        return {
            cdrs : data.rows.map(function(r) {
                p = r.value;
                return p;
            }),
            message : "You are logged in as " + tmp.profile.name,
        }
    } else {
        return {
            cdrs : [ ] ,
            message : "You are not logged in",
        }
    }
};
```

I am confused because, right after reloading the aplication, `$.log(tmp.profile);` is showing "undefined", even though the previous `$.log(tmp);` is clearly showing that the javascript object has indeed a member named `profile` (of type `Object`, with the expected data).

It is even stranger: when the change notification kicks in, `$.log(tmp.profile);` is showing the right data, even though `$.log(tmp);` does not show any change.

What is going on? Am I missing any encapsulation rules here?

Comment: This is using Prototype, right?  I don't get it; you're setting "tmp" to a DOM element, no?  Why would it be an Object? (Oh wait; it's a couchdb thing. Never mind.)

Comment: undefined is not a reserved word and can be set to something else (leading to bugs). The != operator coerces its arguments, you should almost always use === and !== instead.